# Nested monitor in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor, reentrantlock

If I'm using a ReentrantLock in Java... When a thread has the lock of an object and it tries to acquire another lock of a different object, does it release the first one or does it still hold it?

Comment: What makes you think it should release the other implicitly?

Comment: Me neither.. or close for that matter.  There is a reason the OP is asking this question..

Comment: Thank for all your answers

Answer (score 2):

Acquiring a new lock does not release any locks held before. You have to release them explicitly, usually inside a `finally` block.

But always be careful with acquiring several locks at the same time. Always check that you don't cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

Acquiring a lock does not cause a thread to release any other lock it has already acquired. [The API documentation for the Lock interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) states that implementations of Lock can hold multiple locks, and uses a technique (hand-over-hand locking) that would not work unless a thread could hold onto more than one lock at a time (emphasis added):

> While the scoping mechanism for synchronized methods and statements
>   makes it much easier to program with monitor locks, and helps avoid
>   many common programming errors involving locks, there are occasions
>   where you need to work with locks in a more flexible way. For example,
>   some algorithms for traversing concurrently accessed data structures
>   require the use of "hand-over-hand" or "chain locking": you acquire
>   the lock of node A, then node B, then release A and acquire C, then
>   release B and acquire D and so on. **Implementations of the Lock
>   interface enable the use of such techniques by allowing a lock to be
>   acquired and released in different scopes, and allowing multiple locks
>   to be acquired and released in any order**.

Since ReentrantLock implements Lock this should be applicable.